# MySQL Count fields which contains any data

Tags: php, mysql

Problem: I have database where is website column which contains 20results.
When I try to count the amount of websites it returns me 50.

Known Issue:I have 50rows on my database and it returns them all, so it also counts empty spaces, how to prevent counting empty spaces ?

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(website) FROM data";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");      
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    var_dump($row);
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if "website" column is not blank in database

Try this

```
$query ="SELECT COUNT(website) FROM data WHERE (website != '' OR website IS NOT NULL)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE` condition for check for `IS NOT NULL` and blank values.

```
$query ="SELECT COUNT(website) FROM data WHERE website != '' or website IS NOT NULL";
```